# Approach of building a website for local basketball league?

Tags: 7

I am asked to build a local basketball league website.

Functionality is quite simple:

- League news/articles
- Different team page with team news, player info, gallery
- Each player has profile. such as name, height, position, photo.

Module OG seems to be a good match in this case, but I am wondering if it can be done **without OG**.

Are there any other easier approaches?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you tag this as Drupal 7.  You don't need OG unless you want to have groups where members of the group can chat with one another.

Content Types:  League, team, news/articles (maybe Players)
Modules:  Image field, Viewes.

- News & Articles are self explanatory.
- Create node reference fields for Teams & Players
- Teams would node reference league,  players would node reference a team.
- You may only have 1 league or multiple.
- Add fields to players (name, height, position, photo)
- May want to use image style to set defaults size for photos
- Depending on your use, Players can be users or a content type
- Then you will use views to display everything the way you want, such as, team gallery, teams in league, etc.

Also you may want to embed a view into a node.   Use embed_views module